# .htaccess blog folder index.php file not found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I migrated my site from static to wordpress and in interest of maintaining SEO retained the .htm extension on all pages however I have WP installed in folder /blog  with following in root htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,NE]
```

Almost everything works perfectly and google is happy as all links are still unchanged  except for this single URL  https://www.example.com.au/blog/ which instead of displaying https://www.example.com/blog/index.php returns a 404 not found.

The /blog directory has standard wordpress htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php [NC]
</IfModule>
```

I have blundered around for hours with redirects and have tried using the following the /blog .htaccess  but all with no success.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(/[^/]*|)$ $1/index.php$2 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: now your site in sub folder?? is it??

Comment: all site content is in /blog/  but URLs presented to the user and google are [link]https://www.example.com/page.htm  the only page not carried over is the old index.htm